# How does the Enigma machine ensure that no letter is substituted for itself?

Tags: group-theory, permutations, cryptography

In [*Alan Turing: The Enigma*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/069116472X) [Andrew Hodges](http://www.synth.co.uk/main.html) describes how the letter encodings performed by a German Enigma machine "would always be *swappings*" (original emphasis). And goes on to say that

> There was a practical advantage to this Enigma property. It meant that
>   the deciphering operation was identical with the enciphering
>   operation. (In group-theory terms, the cipher was self-inverse). ...
>   But it was associated with a grave weakness, in that the substitutions
>   thus performed were always of this very special kind, with the
>   particular feature that no letter could ever be enciphered into
>   itself.

This passage suggests that *any* encoding that performs swappings, and is thus self-inverse, *must* have the property that no letter is "enciphered into itself". However this isn't the case, is it? Isn't this only a property of "swappings" in which *all* letters are swapped for a *different* letter. That is, doesn't he mean to say that the Enigma substitutions "would always be swappings of *every letter for a different one*" so that the non-substitution of the same letter is enforced by the specific swappings preformed by the machine?

If so, how is the property of "non-self-substitution" achieved by the machine as a whole? I can see that at the reflector is physically constrained to have this property, but the plugboard clearly lacks it, as does at least one rotor (Rotor III substitutes N for N). And in any case, it isn't clear to me how self-substituted in guaranteed to be avoided in all possible configurations and rotor positions.

What specific properties of the components and configuration of the Enigma machine ensure that no letter is substituted for itself? Does it follow from some basic property of permutations, or is it the result of specific wiring configurations, deliberately made to avoid self-substitution?

Comment: Why do you believe the passage suggests what you say it suggests?

Comment: @whacka: "This" refers to property that whatever substitutions were performed would be swapping, but not (as written) that all letters are swapped. "Associated" is a bit less direct, but suggests that the fact that " no letter could ever be enciphered into itself" is a *consequence* of "this".

Comment: I'm not quite sure what the passage is trying to say, but it sounds like if you treat the Enigma machine as a function $f$ taking plaintext and outputting cipertext, then it is an [involution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involution_%28mathematics%29) - i.e. $f(f(x))=x$. This doesn't imply that $f$ has no fixed points (since the identity function is an involution, for instance) - but it could be that the Enigma machine specified so as an additional requirement.

Comment: @Meelo: Correct, and, I think that highlights the question then: what properties of the Enigma (e.g. physical constraints or deliberate design) ensure that no letter is substituted for itself (i.e. that there are no fixed points).

Comment: I don't read that text as implying what you say it implies. Obviously, he is implying that, by a swapping, he means a complete swapping - no fixed letters. He never says any self-inverse cipher must not have a fixed point.

Comment: As for the question, I think this requires way too much knowledge about the interior of Enigma, akin to asking "How does the Mathematica random number generator work?"

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: That *may* indeed be part of the answer: it is a property of the specific wiring arrangements of the rotors that ensures that in all combinations and positions there are no fixed points. Is that the case?

Comment: How the $f(x)$ would I know? You haven't described the Enigma machine enough for this to be a complete question.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: The question is, in part, in fact *whether* such knowledge is required to explain why there are no fixed points. If it is, saying so would be the start of an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At any stage the Enigma machine provided a unique electrical path through the plugboard and rotors from each letter key to the reflector.  The reflector then sent the current back down a *different* path through the rotors and plugboard, so it ended up at a different letter key and that new letter's light. This had two effects:

- at any stage keys were paired (their paths were joined by the reflector) so the same initial set-up would allow encryption and decryption - this was entirely deliberate and an advertised feature
- each letter key had a letter other than itself which it was paired with at each point in time - this was a flaw exploited by Ultra for cryptanalysis, and could have been avoided with a different design of reflector.

Comment: So (1) unique path (through rotors and plugboard, in each direction) combined (critically) with the fact that (2) the reflector *must* perform complete swapping of all letters ensures that the machine as a whole does so. Correct?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius: I am not sure I would use *must* that way. It did always swap/pair different letters, but it could have been designed differently.  It had $26$ keys/letters - if it had had a $27$th and a single reflection back down the incoming route, it would have been more secure.

Comment: Good point. But the key thing is: it's that feature of the *reflector* that drives the whole thing (assuming nothing special about the wiring of the rotors, etc.).

Comment: Yes: the rotors make cryptanalysis difficult (and an extra rotor even more so in the case of Shark), but it was the the reflector design which led to the no non-substitution property.

Comment: What I was missing in thinking about this was the simple fact that (regardless of the details of rotor wiring or position, as long as every letter is connected) there is a *unique path* that connects to a given letter at the begging/end, so that if, as is the case, the reflector switches between these paths, the letter at the begging and end *must* be different.

Answer (score 0):

I've always found it easier to understand the non-self encoding of a key press
by considering the design of the keys on the Enigma keyboard. Each key on
the Enigma keyboard is a two-way switch for the key and its associated lamp.
When key X is pressed, lamp X is on open circuit. As long as key X is held
down lamp X will never light. So, key X will never encode to itself.  See diagram

```
 http://www.matematiksider.dk/enigma/enigma_circuit_big.png
```

Comment: this is wrong. non-self encoding is a property provided by the reflector, not the keyboard. if the complete scrambling subsystem ever "encoded" a letter to itself, which means that only one letter wire would be energized, no lamp would light for that key press. this "bug" never happen because of a property of the reflector: it connects each letter to exactly one different letter. the fact that the keyboard/display combo would malfunction in the presence of self encoding has no bearing at all on why self encoding never happens.

Answer (score 0):

It is two parts.

First the reflector loops backwards through another path separate from what was entered.  Because the path to the reflector is unique, the path out is producing a different character.

Second is that the plug jumpers would effectively cancel out when the same letter was jumped.  The plug is on the input and output sides of the reflector. If the letter was jumped to from result to input, it is also jumping input to result.

They did use double switches, but I do not believe it was required.

Comment: But how does the machine ensure that an intermit step does not result in a self substitution? The fact that any individual step prevents self substitution is not sufficient.